# Sending eMail Through Visual C++/Cli Not Working

Tags: c++-cli

I'm trying to send an email using C++/Cli through gMAil ... This is the code but it is not working , any suggestions?

```
MailMessage^ email=gcnew     
MailMessage("from@From.com","to@to.com","SUBJECT","MESSAGE");
SmtpClient^ smtp=gcnew SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp->EnableSsl=true;   
smtp->UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
smtp->Credentials = gcnew    
System::Net::NetworkCredential("from@from.com","password");
smtp->Send(email);
```

Comment: there is a proxy present... how to overcome this, the proxy uses port 80

Comment: You can try to specify a proxy in your .config file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config    .... but I doubt that your proxy-server will allo CONNECT requests... Normally you have no chance to access SMTP portes directly via a proxy server...

Answer (score 0):

First a small comment: You are not using C++, you are using C++/CLI (.NET).

For a solution, see answer of: [SmtpClient wont authenticate over SSL/TLS (not pointing to gmail)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082315/smtpclient-wont-authenticate-over-ssl-tls-not-pointing-to-gmail)

Alternatively: [How can I send emails through SSL SMTP with the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011245/how-can-i-send-emails-through-ssl-smtp-with-the-net-framework)

If you have a proxy server, you are normally without luck... of course, you can try to specify a proxy server in your config file. For more info see: 
[Is it possible to specify proxy credentials in your web.config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186800/is-it-possible-to-specify-proxy-credentials-in-your-web-config)
But normally your proxy server will not allow CONNECT reqeusts...